# Grid widget not working - Ext JS

Tags: extjs, grid, panel, alias

So I have a grid class that I am defining here:

```
Ext.define('MC.view.portal.MetadataWidget', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    id: 'metadatawid',
    title: 'Graph',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('metadatastore'),
    alias: 'widget.metadatawidget',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.columns = [
            {header: 'KBE Name', dataIndex: 'KBE_NAME', flex: 3, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
            ...//remaining rows
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments); 
    }
});
```

And I am trying to define it in my app.js using it's alias:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            id: 'app_container',
            width: '100%',
            height: 1000,
            renderTo: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            border: false,
            requires: [ 'MC.view.portal.MetadataWidget' ],
            items: [
                { xtype: 'metadatawidget', height: 400, width: ...
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: name is undefined
if (name === from || name.substring(0, from.length) === from) {
```

Besides implementing a controller, this is basically following the same way they define a widget in the Sencha docks, but I cannot find the reason for my error. Any ideas?

-the store works

-directories are fine

-creating the widget causes the trouble

Cheers!

Comment: Have you included `'MC.view.portal.MetadataWidget'` in the `requires` config of `app.js`?

Comment: Well yeah it's right there already isn't it?

Comment: Ohh it goes in the actual app config, okay awesome it worked! Why not put it in an answer so i can give ya an upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included 'MC.view.portal.MetadataWidget' in the requires config of app.js?  That error usually means that the class has not yet been loaded by Ext.